# How to print the longest continuous sequence whose sum of elements is maximum?

Tags: java, list, algorithm, arraylist

**I have a code that outputs a subsequence with the maximum sum, but there is a condition "if there are 2 or more sequences equal in sum, then output the longest of them"** (everything needs to be done using a list). *I do not understand how to display the one that is longer*.In this code the output should be 100 90 8. (the code remembers the very first of these sequences)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(1);
    list.add(2);
    list.add(-5);
    list.add(6);
    list.add(-3);
    list.add(-13434);
    list.add(99);
    list.add(99);
    list.add(-444);
    list.add(-7444);
    list.add(100);
    list.add(90);
    list.add(8);
    if (list == null || list.size() == 0) {//проверка на пустоту листа
        System.out.println("empty array");
        return;
    }

    int maxSumStartIndex = 0;
    int maxSumLastIndex = 0;
    int maxSum = list.get(0);

    int lastSumStartIndex = 0;
    int lastSum = list.get(0);

    for (int i = 1; i < list.size(); i++) {

        lastSum += list.get(i);
        if (lastSum < list.get(i)) {
            lastSum = list.get(i);
            lastSumStartIndex = i;
        }

        if (maxSum < lastSum) {
            maxSumStartIndex = lastSumStartIndex;
            maxSumLastIndex = i;
            maxSum = lastSum;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("sum( arr[" + maxSumStartIndex + "] .. arr[" + maxSumLastIndex + "] ) = " + maxSum);
    for (int i = maxSumStartIndex; i <= maxSumLastIndex; i++) {
        System.out.print(list.get(i) + " ");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: `if (maxSum < lastSum || (maxSum == lastSum && maxSumLength < lastSumLength))`

Comment: Hint: You can create the list with `Arrays.asList(1, 2, -5, ...);` it's a little easier and still in the code, no need to read from anywhere. And the simple form is usually solved with Kadane's algorithm, which you seem to be using too.

Comment: @user3386109 and how to set this length of sums?

Comment: @DavidMSK You have a start index and a current index. What's the length?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works but don't know if its the best approach

```
    int maxSumStartIndex = 0;
    int maxSumLastIndex = 0;
    int maxSum = list.get(0);
    int maxSumLength = 0;

    int lastSumStartIndex = 0;
    int lastSum = list.get(0);

    for (int i = 1; i < list.size(); i++) {
        lastSum += list.get(i);
        if (lastSum < list.get(i)) {
            lastSum = list.get(i);
            lastSumStartIndex = i;
        }
        if (maxSum < lastSum) {
            maxSumStartIndex = lastSumStartIndex;
            maxSumLastIndex = i;
            maxSumLength = maxSumLastIndex - maxSumStartIndex + 1;
            maxSum = lastSum;
        }
        if (maxSum == lastSum) {
            if (!(i - lastSumStartIndex + 1 > maxSumLength)) continue;
            maxSumStartIndex = lastSumStartIndex;
            maxSumLastIndex = i;
            maxSumLength = maxSumLastIndex - maxSumStartIndex + 1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).